# How to add event on google calendar on button click, Android

Tags: android

I want to add event on google calender on button click in android, Please suggest some ways to add

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to add event on Google Calender is using the Calender API by Google.

Refer [Google Calender API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

Other way is putting the event data into Calender using `ContentProvider` exposed.

Reference: [sync event added programmatically with google calendar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918968/sync-event-added-programmatically-with-google-calendar-in-android)