# event vanished after inserting (Above Android 6.0 ) programmatically Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-calendar-api, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-calendar

I add the event directly to the primary calendar by using this code

```
           try {
            val eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events"
            val eventValues = ContentValues()
            eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1)
            eventValues.put("title", "Event Title")
            eventValues.put("description", "nirav Description")
            eventValues.put("eventLocation", "Anand")
            var startMillis: Long = 0
            var endMillis: Long = 0

            try {

                startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()+60*60*10
                endMillis = startMillis+ 60 * 60 * 1000
            } catch (e: ParseException) {
                Log.e("App", e.message)
            }

            eventValues.put("dtstart", startMillis)
            eventValues.put("dtend", endMillis)
            eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1) // 0 for false, 1 for true

            val eventUri = getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues)
            var eventID = java.lang.Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment()!!)

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Sucess:" + eventID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, ex.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

I already checked for the permissions .
I also tried `SYNC_EVENTS` but no luck.

I also referred the following links but the issue still remains unsolved.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918968/sync-event-added-programmatically-with-google-calendar-in-android)